# The type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle' exists in both 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll' and 'System.Runtime.Handles.dll'

Tags: c#, dll, reference, compiler-errors, interop

I'm currently porting a Windows 8.1 app to a Windows 10 UAP app which uses interop to communicate between C++ and C# and I'm having the following error popping up :

> $(ProjectName).Interop.g.cs : error CS0433: The type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle' exists in both 'c:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'
>   and 'c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\lib\McgDependencies\System.Runtime.Handles.dll'

From what I managed to learn about this, `System.Runtime.Handler` is kind of a small part of `System.Runtime.InteropServices` (or at least contains a small part of it).

These two dlls are always referenced by the compiler, so removing them cannot be done.

I checked for the SafeHandle type in my solution and it is not used anywhere other than in the generated file $(ProjectName).Interop.g.cs. I checked the references of all the projects in my solution and none are referencing any of the two dlls mentioned in the error.

Every project builds fine when I build them separately... Only the startup project fails with this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem. It wasn't easy to find but I did it! Since my solution is very specific to my project, I'll post the steps I used to solve it. I hope it can help someone!

1. I unloaded my startup project and created a new empty one.
2. One by one, I added the references needed to the empty project (starting from the one with less dependencies) until I get the error, which gave me the problematic project.
3. I tried removing some references of this project, one at a time until the solution was compiling!

I found that the FlurrySDK for Windows 8 is causing problems in Windows 10, so I disabled it until they publish a Windows 10 version!

Hope this helps someone!